# Is it possible to declare a constexpr pointer instead of a pointer to constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

Is it correct that

```
constexpr int* p = nullptr;
```

declares constexpr pointer (instead of a pointer to constexpr int)?

This definition

```
int* constexpr p = nullptr;
```

gives a compilation error.

Comment: It's the other way around. Try reading it from right to left.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard says in [[dcl.constexpr]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#1.sentence-1) that only variables or functions (and their templates) can be `constexpr`:

> The `constexpr` specifier shall be applied only to the definition of a variable or variable template or the declaration of a function or function template.

In particular, `constexpr` is not part of the type system (although it does imply `const`), so pointer-to-constexpr is not a meaningful concept in C++.

The primary reason to mark variables as `constexpr` is to make them [usable in constant expressions](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#3). However, one can also use references and constant integral values which are initialized with constant initializers within constant expressions. Maybe the reference part could help you solve whatever problem you are dealing with?

Comment: @asynts Fixed. But if it consumed the earliest bracket, shouldn't it use the first one for the link and the second one as text?

Comment: @asynts Ok, that makes sense, but the "backwards" is a pretty important detail there ;)